# I need to multiply 1st Array list with 2nd Array list

Tags: vb.net

In here get value into the arraylist, I'm using MySql database and Tables.

my 1st array list number of items can be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5,

my 2nd array contain number of 5 items.

for example;

arraylist1 = (10,50,50)
arraylist2 = (2.6,2.4,1.7,1.4,1.1)

If when multiplying arraylist together,

total = (10 * 2.6) + (50 * 2.4) + (50 * 1.7)  places can't be changed.

How to do that?

firstly I try with define the arralist2 and it worked.

arraylist2 = (2.6,2.4,1.7,1.4,1.1)

Code;

```
Dim a As Integer = 0

                For Each i In arraylist1
  

                    Ptotal += arraylist2(a) * i

                    a += 1

                Next
```

Comment: It doesn't look to me like there's a library shortcut, so I think you'll have to code what you want it to do directly.  It should be basic coding that doesn't rise to the level of needing further explanation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim a As Integer = 0

                For Each i In distance_range

                    Ptotal += price_rage(a) * i

                    a += 1

                Next
```